# Working with portrait and landscape mode programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create the layouts for both portrait and landscape mode (in java) and change the orientations programmatically in java file. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
    {
        // code to do for Landscape Mode     
    } else {

        // code to do for Portrait Mode  
    }
```